# Passing data into a Vue template

Tags: vue.js

I am fairly new to vue and can't figure out how to add data values within a template. I am trying to build a very basic form builder. If I click on a button it should add another array of data into a components variable. This is working. The I am doing a v-for to add input fields where some of the attributes are apart of the array for that component. I get it so it will add the input but no values are being passed into the input.

I have created a jsfiddle with where I am stuck at. https://jsfiddle.net/a9koj9gv/2/

```
<div id="app">
    <button @click="add_text_input">New Text Input Field</button>
    <my-component v-for="comp in components"></my-component>
    <pre>{{ $data | json }}</pre>
</div>

new Vue({
    el: "#app",

    data: function() {
        return {
            components: [{
                    name: "first_name",
                    showname: "First Name",
                    type: "text",
                    required: "false",
                    fee: "0"
                  }]
            }
    },

    components: {
        'my-component': {
            template: '<div>{{ showname }}: <input v-bind:name="name" v-bind:type="type"></div>',
            props: ['showname', 'type', 'name']
        }

    },

    methods: {
        add_text_input: function() {
            var array = {
                    name: "last_name",
                    showname: "Last Name",
                    type: "text",
                    required: "false",
                    fee: "0"
                  };
            this.components.push(array);
        }
    }
})
```

I appreciate any help as I know I am just missing something obvious.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [props](https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Props) to pass data into the component.

Currently you have `<my-component v-for="comp in components"></my-component>`, which doesn't bind any props to the component.

Instead, do:

```
<my-component :showname="comp.showname" 
              :type="comp.type" 
              :name="comp.name" 
              v-for="comp in components"
></my-component>
```

[Here is a fork of your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/asemahle/x9a6m357/) with the change.

Comment: Thank you.  I knew I was missing something simple.

Comment: Provide a key in the v-for is not mandatory ?

Comment: @Fasco, providing a key is not mandatory, but it is a good idea. You can learn more about when to provide a key in the [documentation here](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#maintaining-state-with-key).

Answer (score 0):

while asemahle got it right, here is a boiled down version on how to expose data to the child component. SFC:

```
  async created() {
    await this.setTemplate();
  },
  methods: {
    async setTemplate() {
      // const templateString = await axios.get..
        this.t = {
          template: templateString,
          props: ['foo'],
        }
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      foo: 'bar',
      t: null
    }
  }
};
</script>

<template>
  <component :is="t" :foo="foo"></component>
```

It pulls a template string that is compiled/transpiled into a js-render-function. In this case with Vite with esm to have a client-side compiler available:

```
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      // https://github.com/vuejs/core/tree/main/packages/vue#with-a-bundler
      vue: "vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js",
```

the index.js bundle size increases by few kb, in my case 30kb (which is minimal)
You could now add some what-if-fail and show-while-loading with [defineasynccomponent](https://vuejs.org/api/general.html#defineasynccomponent)